# Eclipse: did I lose git my changes?

Tags: eclipse, git

I'm working on a project and needed to double back and work from a previous commit. I went team-> show in history  and right clicked the commit, then pressed checkout. After a few hours I committed with a message. I wanted to merge but it was phased out on the right click menu so I tried switching back to master branch and merging. This didn't do anything, so I tried to jump back to the commit branch but it was to old commit without my recent changes. Did I just lose all my work or is there some way to find it?

thanks

Comment: Huh this is weird. Normally you get a warning if you are going to merge or revert and have local changes when you try to commit.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you committed in a detached HEAD state. Now, that is no reason to lose your head, though :-)
What detached HEAD means is that you are not on any branch. In your case it happened because you checked out a commit, which is not a branch. You are still able to commit, but as soon as you switch branches you lose the handle on your new commit, and you cannot go back to it directly.

However, assuming this was pretty recently you should be able to recover it by viewing the reflog. In Eclipse that means opening the Git Repositories view, right-click and select View In -> Git Reflog. You should see your commit identified by the message you used. Right click the appropriate commit, and the select Checkout. Go back to Git Repositories, right click, and select Switch to -> New Branch... Give your branch a name. Now you switch to any branch you wish, and your commit will be safe and sound.